# Centering the navbar using text align or inline-block? (jekyll)

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I'm having difficulty centering my navbar. I've tried replacing "block" with "inline-block" in certain areas that didn't lead to any success. I've also tried "text-align: center" as well but that's not working.
I tried "text-align: " left, right and center but it doesn't change at all anyway. Am I looking in the right spot?
Everything else is functioning as intended so I'm scared to touch anything.
Here's the [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kbuoL6sm/5/)

```
#navbar ul li a, .dropdown-toggle {
  color: white;
  text-align: center; /*doesn't seem to do anything*/
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Share the HTML generated by the code, you can do this by giving `Ctrl+u or View Page Source` in this generated page and copying the HTML contents!

Comment: Something like this? --> https://jsfiddle.net/kbuoL6sm/6/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError man you always come through! Yes!

Comment: I got you covered man :) Answer added - with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to centering elements with `text-align: center` is two-fold:

**1.** Declare `display: block` *and* `text-align: center` on the containing parent element
**2.** Declare `display: inline-block` on the nested children elements

You can center any `inline-block` element this way using `text-align: center` *if* the parent element is a `block` element.

What you will need to adjust your styles accordingly:

```
#navbar ul:not(.dropdown-menu) {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

#navbar ul:not(.dropdown-menu) > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

An important factor to consider anytime you need to align an element is to keep a look out for `float` rules, they will negate any attempt at aligning elements using `display` rules.

**Fiddle Demonstration:**
https://jsfiddle.net/kbuoL6sm/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try `margin: 0 auto;` on the `#navbar`

Or, on the parent of the `#navbar` try `text-align: center;`

If it needs something more than that, css-tricks has a great guide here for centering just about every condition:

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/